# Differences between modern and old mathematical notations

Tags: mathematics, notation, big-list

**Note**: I didn't write the word "ancient" in the title because I want to see the notation from 1400 A.D. to 1700 A.D.
Mathematical notation has changed very much from the past millennium, and new notations are made for new concepts. For example, there was a time when the notations for representing numbers was different in different regions. I saw somewhere a piece of a page from one of Euler's books or articles:
[image]
This is very close to modern notation, but not same as it (for example, the root symbols are larger). After seeing this page, a question cam in my mind:

> What are some major differences in today's notation and notation of 1400 A.D. to 1700 A.D. era?

These differences are to be mentioned:

- Differences in symbols representing numbers, for example, somewhere in an old article (probably of Euler's) the number $1$ was written as $I$ (I thought that it was roman, but 2 was written normally)
- Major differences in "minor notations". For example, while reading Ramanujan's handwritten manuscripts, I found that He wrote $\&c$ instead of the normal $\dots$ in infinite sum. He would have written:
  $$\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\&c$$
  instead of:
  $$\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\dots$$
- Differences in the "texture" of the symbols. For example, in the image I have given above, it can be noticed that the integral symbols and the root symbols are a little bit different.
- Differences in terminology. Many examples are in the first answer, and I think there are very few that he didn't mention. If there are any more, please also mention them.

Like most big list questions, please mention only one difference per answer. If I missed any other difference in symbols case, please mention in the comments or edit the question.

Comment: See [F.Cajori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florian_Cajori)'s [A history of mathematical notations](https://books.google.it/books?id=OQZxHpG2y3UC&printsec=frontcover): you can find (quite) everything in it.

Comment: Besides Cajori's book, in recent years one can also look at older literature yourself without digging through university library stacks for it, and I would encourage you to take advantage of this. For example, see the various old journals freely available you can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2780697/13130) (in the past 15 years I've managed to obtain nearly complete runs of these and many other journals from the 1800s). For titles of journals to search for, see the list [on pp. ix-xlix here](https://archive.org/details/cataloguescie01royaiala/page/n13/mode/2up).

Comment: Let $\pi_0$ denote the value we now denote $\pi$. In Euler's proofs, $\pi$ could denote $\pi_0/2$, $\pi_0$ or $2\pi_0$, whichever was more convenient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## I. Notes on notation and English terms in 1800s literature (primarily related to series)

The following is from the introductory comments for something involving conditionally convergent series I was working on several years ago.

1. **The logarithm function** is often denoted by a lower case L, sometimes italicized (e.g. [Catalan's book](https://archive.org/details/traitlmentaired01catagoog)) and sometimes not italicized (e.g. [Laurent's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=hQfj8Rx_sc4C)). Incidentally, this leads to many instances of *ln* appearing, but these denote the logarithm of $n$ rather than the often now used logarithm function ${\ln}.$ Iterated logarithms were denoted either by consecutive L's or the use of superscripts (e.g. $\ln \ln \ln n$ might be denoted by *llln* or *lll n* or ${l^3}n,$ or by similar expressions in which the lower case L is NOT italicized).
2. $n!$ **(factorial)** was often denoted by placing $n$ within a "partial box" formed by using only the left and bottom sides of a rectangular box. Anytime you are unsure how factorials are denoted in a book, simply look in places where power series expansions of exponential and trigonometric functions appear. However, most of the time a "factorial notation" was not used, and instead the first few terms (and the general term, if not obvious) were written.
3. **Multiplication** was often denoted by a period (easier to typeset than our current centered dot notation), and thus the expression $1.2.3.4$ represents $4! = 24.$
4. Sometimes an **overline bar** (called a *vinculum*) is used instead of parentheses for grouping purposes.
5. **Miscellaneous terms:**

*vulgar fraction* = a quotient of integers written in vertical fraction format

*impossible number* = non-real complex number

*possible number* = real number

*finite value/quantity* = (especially before late 1800s) nonzero value/quantity

*absolute term* =  constant term (e.g. of a polynomial)

*numerically greater* =  absolute value is greater

*algebraically greater* = greater as signed numbers

*contrary signs* = opposite signs

*vanishing fraction* = $0/0$ indeterminate form

*integral rational function* = polynomial

*integral function* = power series

*development* = series expansion

*line* = curve (e.g. not necessarily a straight line)

*right line* or *straight line* = line

*curve of* $n$ *dimensions* = curve of algebraic degree $n$

*rectilinear asymptote* =  linear/oblique asymptote

*invariable quantity* = constant quantity

*squared paper* = graph paper

*the term be wanting* = the term is absent

*equation is rigorous* = exact equality holds

*steadily towards* = monotonically towards

*rigid proof* = rigorous proof

6. **Colloquial journal names:**

*Annales de Gergonne* = Annales de Mathématiques Pures et Appliquées

*Crelle's Journal* and *Borchardt's journal* = Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik

*Darboux's Bulletin* = Bulletin des Sciences Mathématiques et Astronomiques [“et Astronomiques” was later dropped]

*Grunert's Archiv* = Archiv der Mathematik und Physik

*Hoffmann's Journal* = Zeitschrift fur Mathematischen und Naturwissenschaftlichen Unterricht

*Liouville's Journal* = Journal de Mathématiques Pures et Appliquées

*Terquem's journal* = Nouvelles Annales de Mathématiques

## II. Glossary of early to mid 20th century terms in some nowhere differentiable continuous functions literature:

The following list is from near the beginning of [this mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/162605/15780).

*enumerable* = countable

*unenumerable* = uncountable

*progressive derivative* = right derivative

*regressive derivative* = left derivative

*non-dense* = nowhere dense

*everywhere dense* = dense in the smallest interval containing the set (sometimes “dense”, without being prefaced by “everywhere”, means in context “everywhere dense”)

*incrementary ratio* = the ordinary difference quotient that a derivative is the limit of

*line of invariability* (of a function) = an interval on which the function is constant

*the set exists* = the set is not empty.